# How to display rows being hidden

Tags: mysql

I am trying to display all 6 trucks and show the number of stops they make. The display is perfect except for 2 of the trucks not being displayed because their number of stops is 0.

Tried a case statement and ifnull and have no luck.

-- Display each truck’s information and the number of stops they have been to.

```
SELECT 
    trucks.*, 
    COUNT(stops.st_id) AS Number_Of_Stops
FROM shipments
LEFT JOIN 
    trucks ON trucks.T_id = shipments.T_id
LEFT JOIN 
    stops ON shipments.Sh_id = stops.sh_id
GROUP BY 
    t_id;
```

Thank you in advance

Comment: Change your first LEFT JOIN for RIGHT JOIN

Comment: You might check your case on `LEFT JOIN stops ON shipments.Sh_id = stops.sh_id`. Depending on you level of case sensitivity `Sh_id` may not be the same as `sh_id`

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this? I know that your post said that you tried IFNULL, but wanting to make sure in which way you applied it. Also, I am primarily a T-Sql developer, and in that world, I would suggest that your group by be trucks.t_id such that we are assured that t_id is coming from the trucks table and not the shipments table for instance.

```
SELECT 
    trucks.*, 
    IFNULL(COUNT(stops.st_id),0) AS Number_Of_Stops
FROM shipments
LEFT JOIN 
    trucks ON trucks.T_id = shipments.T_id
LEFT JOIN 
    stops ON shipments.Sh_id = stops.sh_id
GROUP BY 
    t_id;
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding IFNULL with that syntax made no change. However, changing the first join to a right join did indeed do the trick.

I want to understand why that fixed the issue rather than just be glad the issue is fixed. Can I not have 2 left joins, or do they always need to be a left/right inner/outer. I know there's an infographic with the different joins - I'll save that for future use.